# React Redux Thunk Chaining Actions Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am making a react app and have been using redux with thunk with some success however, I recently had a need to chain some actions.  The issue I seem to be having is that even the the first action's api call returns a 422, so I'd expect having `Promise.reject(error);` returned would stop the stack from continuing, but it keeps moving down the chain anyway.

Here is some code:

**actions.js**

here is the chained action I'm trying to use:

```
export const resetPasswordAndRefreshUser = (password, password_confirmation) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(resetPassword(password, password_confirmation))
      .then((result) => {

        //// This shouldn't get executed in resetPassword rejects /////
        //// console.log(result) is undefined ////

        return dispatch(getAuthedUser());

      }, (error) =>{
        // Do Nothing
      }).catch((error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }
};
```

And the action definitions themselves:

```
export const resetPassword = (password, password_confirmation) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: authConstants.LOGIN_RESET_REQUEST
    });

    return AuthService.resetPassword(password, password_confirmation)
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch({
          type: authConstants.LOGIN_RESET_SUCCESS
        });
        dispatch({
          type: alertConstants.SUCCESS,
          message: 'Your new password was set successfully.'
        });
        history.push('/');
      }, error => {
        dispatch({
          type: authConstants.LOGIN_RESET_ERROR
        });
        dispatch({
          type: alertConstants.ERROR,
          message: 'Error: ' + error
        });
      });
  }
};


export const getAuthedUser = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: authConstants.LOGIN_AUTHED_USER_REQUEST
    });

    return AuthService.getAuthedUser()
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch({
          type: authConstants.LOGIN_AUTHED_USER_SUCCESS,
          user: result
        });
      }, error => {
        dispatch({
          type: authConstants.LOGIN_AUTHED_USER_ERROR
        });
        dispatch({
          type: alertConstants.ERROR,
          message: 'Error: ' + error
        });
      });
  };
};
```

**service.js**

```
static getAuthedUser = () => {
    return API.get(config.api.url + '/me')
      .then((response) => {
        // Get Current User From LocalStorage
        const vmuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('vmuser'));
        if (vmuser) {
          // Update User & Set Back In LocalStorage
          vmuser.user = response.data;
          localStorage.setItem('vmuser', JSON.stringify(vmuser));
        }
        return response.data;
      }).catch(error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }).finally(() => {})
  };

  static resetPassword = (password, password_confirmation) => {
    return API.post(config.api.url + '/reset', { password, password_confirmation })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('reset error');
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }).finally(() => {})
  };
```

Now the **resetpassword** api call is returning a 422 (as I want, for testing).  But when I look in network requests tab, I still se the **getAuthedUser** call being made, even though the promise should be getting rejected in the **authservice**.

Am I just misunderstanding Promises and when `.then()` should be executed?

Comment: It looks like you've solved your problem yourself, but a word of advice: don't mix `promise.then(..., onRejected)` and `promise.catch()`. Under the hood they do the same thing and by combining them you'll end up with results that don't match what you expect

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thanks for the advice, I'll definitely remove one of them.  Which is preferred?  I guess I assumed `.catch()` would catch exceptions while `(error) => {}` would catch promise rejections.

Comment: They do the same thing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch - I generally prefer to use catch as it’s explicit in its definition

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I think I uncovered the proper way to do this thanks to some further Googling:

in my combined action I've added a check for the current state:

```
// State Updated, Check If Successful
if (true === getState().auth.resetPassword) {
  return dispatch(getAuthedUser());
}
```

So the full code for the combined action looks like this:

```
export const resetPasswordAndRefreshUser = (password, password_confirmation) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(resetPassword(password, password_confirmation))
      .then((result) => {
        // State Updated, Check If Successful
        if (true === getState().auth.resetPassword) {
          return dispatch(getAuthedUser());
        }
      }, (error) => {
        // Do Nothing
      }).catch((error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }
};
```